# Shine effect on Passbook icon

Tags: iphone, ios, passbook

Is it possible to remove the shine from Passbook icon displayed on the Lockscreen while Pass has been updated?

From docs:

> icon.png
>
> The pass’s icon. This is displayed in notifications and in
> emails that have a pass attached, and on the lock screen.     When it
> is displayed, the icon gets a shine effect and rounded corners.

It is possible to remove shine on a strip only with "suppressStripShine" top-level key.

Answer (score 0):

There's no documented API to suppress the icon shine, sorry.

You should go to Apple's [bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and file an enhancement request, explaining how it would add value for you to be able to do this.